# How do I pass my variable from template to views.py

Tags: javascript, django

I wish to know how I can pass the oobcode value to def postresetusername in views.py

```
   reset_username.html  

   <script type="text/javascript">
   var oobcode;
   function func(){
       oobcode = localStorage.getItem("storageName");
   }
   </script>

  views.py

  def postresetusername(request):
    authe.verify_password_reset_code(oobcode,"new_password")
    return render(request, "reset_username.html")
```

Comment: Does the user have to enter some kind of form to reset their username?

Comment: yes , along with the new username I want to pass the oobcode value

Comment: You have to pass data through POST by creating a form.

Comment: email = request.POST.get('email') .This is how I retireve the username in the def postresetusername .But oobcode is just a variable . I dont know how to access it

Answer (score 0):

Your form method should be `method = "post"` and `action = "the url for the view"`

**JQUERY**

```
<script>
$(function(){
            var frm = $('#yourform');

            frm.submit(function (e) {
                var oobcode = localStorage.getItem("storageName");
                e.preventDefault();

                    $.ajax({
                        type: frm.attr('method'),
                        url: frm.attr('action'),
                        data:
                        frm.serialize()+ "&oobcode="+oobcode+"",

            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Submission was successful.');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('An error occurred.');
                console.log(data);

            },
                });    
            });
        });
        </script>
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
  def postresetusername(request):
    oobcode = request.POST.get('oobcode',False)
    authe.verify_password_reset_code(oobcode,"new_password")
    return render(request, "reset_username.html")
```